# Индексирование динамического контента сайта интернет-поисковиками

Tags: asp.net, поиск, оптимизация

Такая проблема.
Есть страница, загружая которую иницируется обращение к базе и выводится информация X.
Мне необходимо сделать так, чтобы эту страницу, НАПОЛНЕННУЮ ИНФОРМАЦИЕЙ X, проиндексировал, например, Google.
Но проблема в том, что сама по себе страница - шаблон - ничего не содержит. Только при её открытии в браузере она наполняется информацией X.

Как решение придумал только создавать временные копии этой страницы с информацией X. Копии - html-файлы, хранящиеся в папке, которую я укажу Google индексировать.
Тогда придётся обновлять эти временные копии, чтобы информация была актуальной. А также модифицировать ссылки. Что не есть хорошо, т.к. требует времени для генерации.

Может кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой и подскажет другое, более эффективное решение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не понимаете самой сути поисковых роботов. Принцип таков, что есть модули (спайдеры, кроулеры и т.д.). Когда Вы дадите гуглу ссылку на главную страницу вебсайта, он войдет, включится спайдер, с главной страницы он надйет и обработает все ссылки на внутренние ресурсы, страницы и т.д. и т.п., затем кроулер и то же самое для внешних ссылок. (Материал не на 100% точный, из институтских знаний, но принцип таков это 100%). Итак какой мы можем сделать вывод:
Если только вы знаете о существовании этой страницы, то тенденция не изменится.
Если есть ссылка на раздел а внутри страницы раздела есть ссылки на отдельные страницы, то материал будет успешно индексироваться. 
Первоначально вам нужно было обратиться к Этому Самому Поиску Гугла

Comment: Ну вот смотрите: именно это Ваше сообщение хранится в базе данных.
Есть страница ViewForumThread.aspx.
Пусть у нас такой адрес: http://hashcode.ru/ViewForumThread.aspx?Thread=100500.
Где 100500 - номер вопроса в форуме. Если Thread=100500, то Ваше сообщение будет отображаться, а если  Thread=777, то нет. Т.е. содержимое страницы зависит от выбранной темы. 
Google ищет по ключу "Принцип таков, что есть модули (спайдеры, кроулеры и т.д.)". 
!!!СМ СЛЕДУЮЩИЙ КОММЕНТАРИЙ!!!!

Comment: На странице http://hashcode.ru/ViewForumThread.aspx такого текста нет (это просто шаблон), с параметром Thread=777 - тоже нет. Есть только тут: http://hashcode.ru/ViewForumThread.aspx?Thread=100500.

Или гугл генерирует все возможные значения параметров???

Comment: ок, а как пользователь может попасть на страницу ViewForumThread.aspx?Thread=100500 ? Как и сказал @stck, если существует "путь" по ссылкам от главной страницы сайта до той, которая нас интересует, то поисковик ее найдет.

Comment: Вы не поняли немного. Допустим есть темплейт у которого нет параметра, без параметра он отображает каталог. То есть если мы зайдем на mysite.com/index.aspx то гугл проиндексирует каталог (допустим http://hashcode.ru/questions/). Найдет все ссылки типа ".../questions/номер".
Пройдет по каждой из этих ссылок, т.е. получит например "...ru/questions/25775/" и проиндексирует страницу по этой ссылке. Далее возьмет следующую (!СЛЕДУЩУЮ ССЫЛКУ НА СТРАНИЦЕ!) ссылку. И так далее. Когда он дойдет до меню странице (1 - 2 - 3 ...) перейдет на следущую и повторит действия.

Comment: "Он видит страницы страницы как вы, но в разметке. И даже если........ Если не знаешь ссылки на страницу, ты на нее никогда не попадёшь...."
@stck, вот в этом и вся проблема.
Тогда, как только появляется новый вопрос, прописывать его адрес на какую-нибудь фэйковую страницу, который поисковик 100% проиндексирует?

Comment: Да нет же! Зайдите в http://hashcode.ru/questions/ и откройте исходный код. Вы видете что нет скриптов?? Вот так видит краулер любую  страницу сгенерированную. 
По шагам: 1. Мы вводим http://hashcode.ru/ скрипт генерирует страницу на которой есть ссылка http://hashcode.ru/questions/
2. Кроулер переходит на нее. Скрипт генерирует каталог. Кроулер получает исходный код, такой же как и вы.
3. Кроулер парсит ссылки на странице и в это время индекс каталога сохраняетсся куда-либо. 
4. У него есть массив ссылок со страницы каталога. Он переходит по каждой и парсит эту страницу, так же сохраняя данн

Comment: ые. 5. Когда перейди со ссылки на ссылку на ссылку на ссылку и т.д. он замыкается - он заканчивает индексирование.
Мораль: Он не видит ваших исходных кодов, так же как и вы смотря исходный код страницы. Потому что посылает запрос, сервер выполняет скрипт и отдаёт страницу. Напишите мне свой адрес, я куплю и вышлю вам книгу по сетевым технологиям

Comment: Ага! Просто я думал, что поисковик не видит страницу как пользователь в браузере, а видит как файл. Спасибо, разобрался.

P.S. Про книгу: сарказм тут неуместен, если же это не был сарказм, то скажите: что за книга?

Comment: Нет, это не был сарказм - Компьютерные сети - В.Г. Олифер, Н.А. Олифер
ну и лучше вместе с Сетевое администрирование на основе Windows Server 2003 - Котельников. Прошу прощения если пред. коммент показался оскорбительным.

Answer (score 1):

Под динамическим формированием вы понимаете наполнение через AJAX? С весны 2010 года гугл поддерживает индексацию сайтов основанных на AJAX. Почитать, как это происходит (похоже на вашу идею) и что для этого нужно сделать, можно [здесь](http://code.google.com/intl/de/web/ajaxcrawling/index.html).

Comment: почитайте комментарий на ответ @stck, там описал идею по-потробней:)